qbo3 update XmlData from TSQL
I have a qbo3 statement where I want to modify a value in my ImportForm.XmlData.
For example, I have the following data in XmlData:
<ImportFormXml>
  <Foo>Bar</Foo>
</ImportFormXml>

I would like the ability to:

modify Foo
add a node NewField, and
remove a node OldField

Can this be done via TSQL (in a qbo3 statement)?

Given ImportForm.XmlData of:
<ImportFormXml>
  <Foo>Bar</Foo>
</ImportFormXml>

You can use the TSQL modify clause as follows:
DECLARE @ID int = 1

-- Add a new key/value pair
UPDATE ImportForm
SET XmlData.modify('
    insert <NewField>NewValue</NewField>
    into (/ImportFormXml)[1]
')
WHERE ImportFormID = @ID

-- Update a key to a new value
UPDATE ImportForm
SET XmlData.modify('replace value of (/ImportFormXml/Foo/text())[1] with "Baz"')
WHERE 
    ImportFormID = 2
    AND XmlData.exist('(/ImportFormXml/Foo)[1]') = 1;
    
-- Delete an existing key
UPDATE ImportForm
SET XmlData.modify('delete /ImportFormXml/OldField')
WHERE 
    ImportFormID = @ID
    AND XmlData.exist('(/ImportFormXml/OldField)[1]') = 1;

Note that you can only manpulate a single Xml node field per UPDATE clause using this technique.
